# Add to Existing Contact from Mail.app to Contacts.app

Tags: macos, mac, mail.app, contacts

I am looking for an option to add the choice "Add to Existing Contact" from the Apple Mail.app *From* address field.  As you all know, we have "Copy Address, Add to VIPs, New Email, Add to Contacts, and Services" as current choices.  I am hoping that I can find a way to have an additional choice of "Add to Existing Contact" to this list - maybe listed under Services.

I know that this is a choice when you use the smart detection feature from a signature.  I also know this is an option in iOS 6. So how can I get the same functionality for From: addresses in Mail.app?

Answer (score 3):

This is a quick look at this,. which means it can either be refined or there is a better answer.

I will assume you know how to create an automator service. So here is an image showing the setup.

[image]

Applescript 1:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set bigList to {}
    tell application "Contacts"

        repeat with i from 1 to number of items in input
            set this_item to item i of input
            copy name of this_item to end of bigList
        end repeat
    end tell
    return bigList
end run
```

Applescript 2:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "Mail"
        set eachMessage to item 1 of (get selection)
        set theExtractAddress to extract address from (sender of eachMessage)
    end tell
    tell application "Contacts"
        set thisPerson to first person whose name is item 1 of input

        make new email at end of emails of thisPerson with properties {label:"home", value:theExtractAddress}
        save
    end tell

end run
```

It will ask for permission to access the Addressbook the first time you run it.
And is a bit slow to return the search results. but worked in my test.

Comment: I do know how to do an automator service.  Thanks so much for your help.  I will try right away and let you know if it works.  THANKS!

Comment: It worked!  This is wonderful.  Thank you.  Do you know of a way I can assign a keyboard combo to activate this script?

Comment: read this apple tech note on how http://support.apple.com/kb/PH3957